# "I've been closer to you more today than I'd hoped to be in a life time."

Tags: grammar

I know the meaning of the sentence and the grammar that is applied here, but it just doesn't seem right to me. I would leave "more" out. Am I right or is that an acceptable thing to do informal speech?

Here it is in context:

> The two of them stumbled and fell onto the walkway, Mark on top.
>
> “Kid,” Alec said. “I’ve been closer to you more today than I’d hoped
>   to be in a lifetime.”

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're quite right in thinking it's a bad construction. Syntactically there's no difference between the cited example and *We're **more closer** than ever* - which is complete garbage.

Comment: I took this sentence from american novel.  For all i know it mimics an every day conversation, and I guess it shouldn't sound that weird for a native speaker, it's been written by an american novelist after all.

Comment: I'd leave the more out, or swap the order of more and today.

Comment: @Gábor: If you'd give us a link to the *full* context, it might be possible to establish whether the writer himself is "incompetent", or if he's simply portraying a "not-very-articulate" (fictional) character. Because of the word order, even a native speaker might not notice the "doubling-up" of comparatives - most people make lots of minor errors in speech anyway. And although I can't see it myself, someone might want to excuse it on the grounds that ***closer*** refers to "...than *normal*" whereas ***more*** refers to "...than all previous periods of closeness added together".

Comment: Thank you, your explanation makes a lot of sense. It's a book from James Dashner, the writer of the maze runner series. Here's the link to that part.

Comment: https://books.google.hu/books?id=dZdGBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT125&lpg=PT125&dq=“I’ve+been+closer+to+you+more+today+than+I’d+hoped+to+be+in+a+lifetime.+Now+make+sure+you+don’t+fall+off+the+edge&source=bl&ots=1mSg_MU6Tw&sig=dyFQ-5a_SheXLdP73lq6hFHAX3c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMIofWN-9auyAIVwt4sCh2nXAzF#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CI%E2%80%99ve%20been%20closer%20to%20you%20more%20today%20than%20I%E2%80%99d%20hoped%20to%20be%20in%20a%20lifetime.%20Now%20make%20sure%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20fall%20off%20the%20edge&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if *I'd hoped* is right or not, but I would prefer using "I would have hoped" in its place.

Comment: I was thinking about that, too. Why would writer write something like that, then?